# Пользовательский конструктор копирования/перемещения

Tags: c++, c++11, конструктор, оператор-присваивания, конструктор-копирования

Правильно ли я понимаю, что будет плохой техникой реализовывать конструкторы копирования/перемещения, используя соответствующие операторы присваивания?

Т.е. лучше ли использовать списки инициализации, соответственно, в случае перемещения в них надо указывать дополнительно при надобности приведение к `rvalue` с помощью `std::move()`, а в теле перемещающего конструктора «обнулить» `rhs` (это по соглашению проекта)? Ну и какие-то дополнительные операции в теле, например, копирование поэлементное массива или логирование.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще говоря, да, это будет странной техникой.

С общей точки зрения попытки реализовать конструктор копирования через копирующий оператор присваивания будут страдать от проблемы "двойной инициализации": так как оператор присваивания ожидает на вход уже сконструированные объекты, в конструкторе придется сначала конструировать какой-то (пустой) объект, а лишь затем вызывать для него оператор присваивания, который будет "переконструировать" этот объект по-новому.

В устоявшихся идиомах обычно делают *наоборот*: копирующий оператор присваивания реализуется через конструктор копирования. Так это делается, например, в известной идиоме Copy-And-Swap.

Comment: https://vsukhachev.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/c0x-rvalue-выражения-и-move-конструктор/ - вот в этой статье есть фрагмент кода, где оператор перемещающего присваивания вызывается в перемещающем к-ре. Увидел, стал сомневаться, теперь сомнения окончательно развеялись. Благодарю.

Comment: @Jenssen: Статья содержит грубейшие ошибки. Оператор присваивания (как копирующий, так и перемещающий) всегда должен полагать, что в объекте-получателе уже содержатся какие-то  "старые" данные. Эти "старые" данные надо сначала освободить, а затем на их место скопировать/переместить "новые" данные из правой части. В статье в реализации перемещающего  оператора присваивания такого освобождения "старых" данных нет вообще. (В копирующем есть, а в перемещающем вдруг куда-то все пропало.) Это - очевидная грубейшая ошибка. А все остальное вытекает уж из этого...

Comment: Еще такой вопрос: в чем различие (подр. эффективность/надежность) между использованием в перемещающем к-ре списков инициализации И вызова делегирующего к-ра (так это называется? - после : вызов к-ра по умолчанию) и применения swap в теле к-ра?